# Lock free doubly linked skip list

Tags: lock-free, doubly-linked-list, skip-lists

There exists tons of research on lock-free doubly linked list. Likewise, there is tons of reserach on lock-free skip lists. As best I can tell, however, nobody has managed a lock free doubly linked skip list. Does anybody know of any research to the contrary, or a reason why this is the case?

Edit: 
The specific scenario is for building a fast quantile (50%, 75%, etc) accumulator. Samples are inserted into the skip list in O(log n) time. By maintaining an iterator to the current quantile, we can compare the inserted value to the current quantile in O(1) time, and can easily determine whether the inserted value is to the left or right of the quantile, and by how much the quantile needs to move as a result. It's the left move that requires a previous pointer.

As I understand it, any difficulty will come from keeping the previous pointers consistent in the face of multiple threads inserting and removing at once. I imagine the solution will almost certainly involve a clever use of pointer marking.

Comment: So every time you add an item to the list you want to go and adjust your quantile data so each quantile knows its starting value, range, and also a pointer to the starting item in the quantile?  I'm guessing, that calculating the quantile information on a request basis if the skip list is dirty, is too slow?

Comment: @johnnycrash Each time you insert you know the value of each quantile, so you know whether the new value is greater or less than the quantile, and as such whether the quantile needs to be moved forward or backwards by a unit. I'm not sure what you mean by range; the quantile is always a single value. In the scheme I ultimately used the constant factor of the skip-list method was higher than a naive method, but it scaled extremely well as the number of operations increased. The cost to update the quantile was constant per insert.

Answer (score 0):

But why would you do such a thing?  I've not actually sat down and worked out exacty how skip lists work, but from my vague understanding, you'd never use the previous pointers.  So why have the overhead of maintaining them?

But if you wanted to, I don't see why you cannot.  Just replace the singly linked list with a doubly linked list.  The doubly linked list is logically coherent, so it's all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea for you.  We use a "cursor" to find the item in a skiplist.  The cursor also maintains the trail that was taken to get to the item.  We use this trail for delete and insert - it avoids a second search to perform those operations, and it embeds the version # of the list that was seen when the traversal was made.  I am wondering if you could use the cursor to more quickly find the previous item.

You would have to go up a level on the cursor and then search for the item that is just barely less than your item.  Alternatively, if the search made it to the lowest level of the linked list, just save the prev ptr as you traverse.  The lowest level is probably used 50% of the time to find your item, so performance would be decent.

Hmm... thinking about it now, it seems that the cursor would 50% of the time have the prev ptr, 25% of the time need to search again from 1 level up, 12.% 2 levels up, etc.  So in infrequent cases, you have to almost do the search entirely again.

I think the advantage to this would be that you don't have to figure out how to "lock free" maintain a double linked skip list, and for the majority of cases you dramatically decrease the cost of locating the previous item.

Comment: A skiplist generally has a static maximum height, so a search operation can populate an array of pointers to the rightmost node traversed at each level.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to maintaining backlinks, when a quantile needs to be updated, you could do another search to find the node whose key is less than the current one. As I also just mentioned in a comment to johnnycrash, it's possible to build an array of the rightmost node found at each level -- and from that it would be possible to accelerate the second search. (Fomitchev's thesis mentions this as a possible optimization.)